# Conditional removal of last row in group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I do have the following dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'case':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,6,6,6,6,6,3,3,3,3,3,3], 
                    'action':['A','B','C','B','D','A','B','B','D','A','B','B','D','A','F','A','B','C','B','D','A']})

    case action
0      1      A
1      1      B
2      1      C
3      1      B
4      1      D
5      1      A
6      2      B
7      2      B
8      2      D
9      2      A
10     6      B
11     6      B
12     6      D
13     6      A
14     6      F
15     3      A
16     3      B
17     3      C
18     3      B
19     3      D
20     3      A
```

If within a `case`-group the 2nd last `action` value is a `D` and the last `action` value of a is an `A` then the last row must be removed.
The result should be:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'case':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,6,6,6,6,6,3,3,3,3,3], 
                    'action':['A','B','C','B','D','B','B','D','B','B','D','A','F','A','B','C','B','D']})

    case action
0      1      A
1      1      B
2      1      C
3      1      B
4      1      D
5      2      B
6      2      B
7      2      D
8      6      B
9      6      B
10     6      D
11     6      A
12     6      F
13     3      A
14     3      B
15     3      C
16     3      B
17     3      D
```

Tried pretty much anything. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Thanks for the re-edit @azro. Will do better next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### `groupby`, `tail` and `shift`

```
t = df1.groupby('case').tail(2)
m = t['action'].eq('A') & t.groupby('case')['action'].shift().eq('D')
df1.drop(m[m].index)
```

#### Explanations

`Group` the dataframe `df1` by `case` and select the last `2` rows from each group using `tail(2)`

```
>>> t

    case action
4      1      D
5      1      A
8      2      D
9      2      A
13     6      A
14     6      F
19     3      D
20     3      A
```

Now `group` the dataframe `t`  by `case` and `shift` the column `action` downwards one unit

```
>>> t.groupby('case')['action'].shift()

4     NaN
5       D
8     NaN
9       D
13    NaN
14      A
19    NaN
20      D
Name: action, dtype: object
```

Create a boolean masks by comparing `action` column with `A` and shifted `action` column with `D` respectively, then take the logical and of both the masks

```
>>> m

4     False
5      True
8     False
9      True
13    False
14    False
19    False
20     True
Name: action, dtype: bool
```

`Drop` the rows in the dataframe `df1` corresponding to index in mask `m` having `True` values

```
>>> df1.drop(m[m].index)

    case action
0      1      A
1      1      B
2      1      C
3      1      B
4      1      D
6      2      B
7      2      B
8      2      D
10     6      B
11     6      B
12     6      D
13     6      A
14     6      F
15     3      A
16     3      B
17     3      C
18     3      B
19     3      D
```

Comment: Great explanation! And works super fast. Thanks for that

Answer (score 2):

You can also check if each group's last two `action` values are `D,A`. If `action.tail(2).eq(['D','A']).all()` then return only the indexes `[:-1]`:

```py
(df1.groupby('case')
    .apply(lambda g: g[:-1] if g.action.tail(2).eq(['D','A']).all() else g)
    .reset_index(drop=True))

#     case action
# 0      1      A
# 1      1      B
# 2      1      C
# 3      1      B
# 4      1      D
# 5      2      B
# 6      2      B
# 7      2      D
# 8      3      A
# 9      3      B
# 10     3      C
# 11     3      B
# 12     3      D
# 13     6      B
# 14     6      B
# 15     6      D
# 16     6      A
# 17     6      F
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```py
import pandas as pd

# data from you
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'case':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,6,6,6,6,6,3,3,3,3,3,3], 
                    'action':['A','B','C','B','D','A','B','B','D','A','B','B','D','A','F','A','B','C','B','D','A']})

# loop over all cases
for c in df1.case.unique():
    # use a temp dataframe, just for readability
    temp = df1[df1['case']==c]
    # check your condition
    if (temp.iloc[-1].action == 'A') & (temp.iloc[-2].action == 'D'):
        # drop the unnecessary row
        df1.drop(temp.index[-1], inplace=True)

# reset the index to be from 0 to 17
df1.reset_index()
```

This gives you:

```
|    |   index |   case | action   |
|---:|--------:|-------:|:---------|
|  0 |       0 |      1 | A        |
|  1 |       1 |      1 | B        |
|  2 |       2 |      1 | C        |
|  3 |       3 |      1 | B        |
|  4 |       4 |      1 | D        |
|  5 |       6 |      2 | B        |
|  6 |       7 |      2 | B        |
|  7 |       8 |      2 | D        |
|  8 |      10 |      6 | B        |
|  9 |      11 |      6 | B        |
| 10 |      12 |      6 | D        |
| 11 |      13 |      6 | A        |
| 12 |      14 |      6 | F        |
| 13 |      15 |      3 | A        |
| 14 |      16 |      3 | B        |
| 15 |      17 |      3 | C        |
| 16 |      18 |      3 | B        |
| 17 |      19 |      3 | D        |
```